# Blocking file requests with a 503

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been experiencing attempts to access certain scripts within my sites CMS from Chinese IP addresses.

These appear to be hacking attempts and despite removing the files I would like to block requests for them with a 503 rather than the 403 generated by the htaccess code below, as I've been advised this is best practice in the situation.

```
<files foo.php>
Deny from all
</files>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Look at this :http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/block-unwanted-users-from-your-site-using-htaccess

Comment: block at the firewall level. don't even let them get CLOSE to apache.

Comment: Thanks N00b UnChained, I've looked into blocking the IP's but there are too many for it to be effective - as they are all directed at specific files I figured that would be the best approach.

Comment: Marc - I don't have access to the firewall, the site is on a shared host.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles: First thing make sure .htaccess & mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `RewriteRule` without a substitution and return the desired `503` status code

```
RewriteRule foo.php - [R=503,L]
```

You can add multiple rules, if there is more than just this file, or use a [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex), like

```
RewriteRule (?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py) - [R=503,L]
```

As an alternative, you can look into [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), which offer more or less the same.

If you have lots of files, you can also see into [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), which allows maintaining a list externally as a [`txt`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) file or [`dbm`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm) hash file, for example.

Comment: Thanks Olaf - what is the function of the L and can you chain filenames together easily? i.e. foo.php, footoo.php

Comment: @toomanyairmiles The [`L flag`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) means, if the rule matches, this should be the last rule. Theoretically, you can add as many filenames as you like, but if there are too many, it will become unmaintainable eventually. See also updated answer.

Comment: In practice this seems to be generating a 404?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles No, when I tried `www.example.com/foo.php` in my test environment, I received a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" status. Do you still have `<Files ...>Deny ...</Files>` or some other directive causing this?

Comment: Definitely removed the previous directive.

Comment: Hi Olaf - I got this working, the issue was the position of the code within (a very busy) htaccess file. Thank you for your help.