# Include/exclude certain files when blocking files with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109208/blocking-file-requests-with-a-503) I'm blocking attempts by bots to hack my web application using this RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule (?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py) - [R=503,L]
```

However, while I need to block access to `foo.php` with a 503 I also need access to `naked-foo.php` which the above code blocks.

Is there any way of specifically excluding a group of URLs from the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex), I gave, seems to be too broad. It blocks all requests *containing* `foo.php`, `bar.pl` or `baz.py`. If you want to block exactly `/foo.php` and so on, you can wrap the pattern with `^...$`

```
RewriteRule ^(?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py)$ - [R=503,L]
```

When the scripts can be in subdirectories, prefix with a slash

```
RewriteRule /(?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py)$ - [R=503,L]
```

You can also use more than one rule

```
RewriteRule ^(?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py)$ - [R=503,L]
RewriteRule /(?:foo.php|baz.py)$ - [R=503,L]
RewriteRule /bar.pl$ - [R=503,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^foo.php$ - [R=503,L]
RewriteRule /foo.php$ - [R=503,L]
RewriteRule /bar.pl$ - [R=503,L]
RewriteRule baz.py - [R=503,L]
```

and be as specific or as broad, as you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add files to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (1.php|2.html|3.txt) [NC]

# Or add file types to exclude (Remove the previous condition if used)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|html|js)     [NC]

RewriteRule  .* - [L]

# Your rule
RewriteRule (?:foo.php|bar.pl|baz.py) - [R=503,L]
```